# Optimize a complex SQL query

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

I'm sure there is a better way to do this. It looks at an `applications` table and collects all applications of a certain status for each job.

So it looks like this:

```
pending | screened | interviewed | accepted | offer | hired | job title
0         0          0             0          0       2       dirt mover
2         0          1             1          0       1       tree planter
7         2          1             1          1       3       hole digger
```

Here is the sql (with extra union columns removed for readability, if you can call this query readable)

```
select sum(pending) as pending, sum(screened) as screened, sum(interviewed) 
as interviewed, sum(accepted) as accepted, sum(offer) as offer, sum(hired) 
as hired, sum(declined) as declined, sum(rejected) as rejected, title, jobid
 from 
(

(select count(j.job_id) as pending, j.title as title, j.job_id as jobid from 
applications a, jobs j where j.job_id = a.job_id and status = 'Pending' group by 
j.job_id)

union

(select count(j.job_id) as screened, j.title as title, j.job_id as jobid from 
applications a, jobs j where j.job_id = a.job_id and status = 'Screened' group by 
j.job_id)

union

(select count(j.job_id) as interviewed, j.title as title, j.job_id as jobid from 
applications a, jobs j where j.job_id = a.job_id and status = 'Interviewed' group by 
j.job_id)

union

(select count(j.job_id) as accepted, j.title as title, j.job_id as jobid from 
applications a, jobs j where j.job_id = a.job_id and status = 'Accepted' group by 
j.job_id)

union

(select count(j.job_id) as offer, j.title as title, j.job_id as jobid from 
applications a, jobs j where j.job_id = a.job_id and status = 'Offer Made' group by 
j.job_id)

union

(select count(j.job_id) as hired, j.title as title, j.job_id as jobid from 
applications a, jobs j where j.job_id = a.job_id and status = 'Offer Accepted' group
 by j.job_id)

union

(select count(j.job_id) as declined, j.title as title, j.job_id as jobid from 
applications a, jobs j where j.job_id = a.job_id and status = 'Offer Declined' group
 by j.job_id)

union

(select count(j.job_id) as rejected, j.title as title, j.job_id as jobid from 
applications a, jobs j where j.job_id = a.job_id and status = 'Rejected' group by 
j.job_id)

) as summ group by title order by title
```

Here is SHOW CREATE TABLE applications

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `applications` (
  `app_id` int(5) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `job_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `reviewed` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`app_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `app_id` (`app_id`),
  KEY `job_id` (`job_id`),
  KEY `status` (`status`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2720 ;
```

Here is SHOW CREATE TABLE jobs

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jobs` (
  `job_id` int(5) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `title` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`app_id`),
  KEY `job_id` (`job_id`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: What do you need? What are you expecting to get from the query?

Comment: A result set faster than 11 seconds. The resulting table is at the top of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are doing a `PIVOT` / cross tab query. Something like this should do the trick.

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE
               WHEN status = 'Pending' THEN 1
             END) AS pending,
       COUNT(CASE
               WHEN status = 'Screened' THEN 1
             END) AS screened,
       /*Remaining ones left as an exercise for the reader*/
       title
FROM   applications a
       JOIN jobs j
         ON j.job_id = a.job_id
GROUP  BY title
ORDER  BY title
```

Answer (score 0):

First, some things to note:

1. Don't use cross joins (Theta joins). This really slows your query down.:

   SELECT * FROM table_1,table_2 WHERE table_1.id = table_2.t1_id

Use instead:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 INNER JOIN table_2 ON(table_1.id = table_2.t1_id)
```

1. PRIMARY KEYs are already UNIQUE KEYS

Now, here's the way I'd do it:

```
SELECT
    SUM(a.app_id),
    a.status
FROM
    applications a INNER JOIN   
    jobs j ON (j.job_id=a.job_id)
GROUP BY
    j.job_id,
    a.status
```

For this simple query you should get something similar to:

```
JOB_TITLE    | STATUS        |   COUNT
dirt mover   | pending       |    0
dirt mover   | screened      |    0
dirt mover   | interviewed   |    0
dirt mover   | accepted      |    0
dirt mover   | offer         |    0
dirt mover   | hired         |    2

tree planter | pending       |    2
tree planter | screened      |    0
tree planter | interviewed   |    1
tree planter | accepted      |    1
tree planter | offer         |    0
tree planter | hired         |    1
...
```

Note that the title is repeated, but that's not a problem, becouse you can get the same information. The query will be several times faster, and simpler.